# .htaccess file making new domain redirect to my original domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

To give a little background that may help understand this. I only had one domain on my host's server initially. I just added a new domain and it was redirecting to my first site.

I had to create an .htaccess file redirect my first site so that it would have my SSL on every page and so that it took the www. away from the sites name. The www. was causing issues with sessions when a customer would login.

So my code was like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The tech support of my host company said that this line was making my new site redirect to my old site:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

How can I make my code work so that is still has the exact same functionality of what it was doing and not interfere with my new domain and make it re-route to my old site?

Comment: That line redirects to the same host but without the www, is your old site without the www?

Comment: The new site doesn't matter if it has www. or not. I just can't have the new site redirected to my other site, but I still need my one site to have that .htaccess file

Comment: Then I doubt it's that line that is redirecting to your old site. If the request was made to the new site, that line redirects to the new site without the www, if the request was made to the old site, that line redirects to the old site without www.

Comment: What would be causing this then? I just need both domains to work and I need to use this .htaccess code for my first site without interfering with the new one.

Comment: Must be something in the site itself... That can be the only explanation. You'll need to review the code to determine what's going on.

Comment: I don't have anything in the new site yet. With this .htaccess code is in my public_html folder. example.com(first site) works just like it should. Then my new site (example2.com) tries to reroute to example.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just exclude the new site, if I am understanding correctly?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://oldsite.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://oldsite.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Alternatively maybe you can just tell it to not do anything based on the host. Try putting this at the top of your rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Note I haven't tested this.

Comment: That is giving me This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for my first site

Comment: I updated the rules. Clear your cache and try it again.

Comment: The new site I just need it to not disturb the site I created first. I just want when the new sites domain is typed into the browser, it goes to that site.

Comment: I haven't tested the new way you put in, but the update made this work. Thanks!